# Splash screen doesn't load

Tags: android, splash-screen

Part of my project I want use a splash screen. Everything is fine with the code, but unfortunately the splash screen doesn't load at the starting.
My manifest file is

```
    <activity 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name="com.example.GamePlay.SplashScreen" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">  </activity>

 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

<activity
    android:name="com.example.GamePlay.Game"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {
        int wait = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();
                while (wait < 2000) {
                    sleep(100);
                    wait += 100;}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("SplashScreen()"+e.toString());
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Final statment for run()");
            }           }       };
    welcomeThread.start();
     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)                      SplashScreen.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Game.cachedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_game, null, false);
                    return null;
                }
               @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Game.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }.execute();
        }       }
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Put the intent-filter **inside** the splash activity manifest element.

Comment: I'd seriously recommend you learn more about Android. Looking at the code and XML you posted, the whole thing is doomed to failure right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should close the activity after the intent-filter and second activity had no intent-filter ..

```
<activity 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name="com.example.GamePlay.SplashScreen" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">

 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.example.GamePlay.Game"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GAME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I think @maria has been member for 7 months ;). Just kidding.

Comment: so it waits for 2 seconds but logo doesn't appear?

Comment: hi Mr @AhmedEkri Is it Really Correct? Your answer is will work but while running the app it will show two application icon...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to put that intent filter inside your activity tag.

At the moment its not tied to an activity and therefore doesn't load at launch.

```
 <activity 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name="com.example.GamePlay.SplashScreen" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps to display splash:-

1.Desgin Your Splash XML.

2.Add Your splash.java File.

3.In last call It on AndroidMainfest File.

In Your Java File Include Intent Like this:-

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private long splashDelay = 5000; //5 seconds

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreen.this, SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }

    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can have a great code and the problem may be in the IDE you're using. If on IDE's such as IntelliJ IDEA, just load the app onto the AVD(hopefully it successfully runs-but bypasses the splashscreen), then reload the AVD (or close it and start it up again).Launch the app from the AVD-do not build it again-from the IDE. You'll notice the spalshscreen will be displayed with the delay time that you set.
Hope this helps you and happy Android Coding. ☺.